# How to get the href link from nested HTML tags using python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have used to below code to extract the href content

```
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
pagesize_content = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':"pull-right"})
print(pagesize_content)
```

When I the class "Pull-right"
output as below

```
[<div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-default closebutton" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="Name Properties" type="submit">
                                Submit
                                <em class="fa fa-check"></em>
</button>
</div>, <div class="pull-right">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled">
<a class="disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            First
                            <em class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></em>
</a>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a href="/Test/country?page=1">1</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="/Test/country?page=2">2</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="/Test/country?page=3">3</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="/Test/country?page=4">4</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="/Test/country?page=4">
                            Last
                            <em class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></em>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>]
```

From that how to extract the href link.

When I try with

```
print(pagesize_content.ul.li.a['href'])
```

error displaying

```
pagesize_content = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':"fa fa-angle-double-right"},href=True)
print(pagesize_content)
```

empty output

Comment: Typo: you have `ul.ui.a` where you wanted `ul.li.a`.

Comment: Why selenium is tagged  ?

Comment: brother share the page link then I check why he not give href link